How do I change my Laravel Docker app to testing environment?
I have this simple docker-compose.yml config for my Laravel app:
services:
    acme-app:
        container_name: acme-app
        build:
            context: ./devops/php
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./devops/php/custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
        networks:
            - acme-network

    acme-server:
        container_name: acme-server
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: nginx:1.27.0-alpine
        ports:
            - ${FORWARD_APP_PORT:-8000}:80
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./devops/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        networks:
            - acme-network
networks:
    acme-network:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    acme-mariadb:


app.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass acme-app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}

Then I can just access it via localhost:8000, the problem is, there's no way for it to load my testing variables, I need that Laravel bootstrap loading it.
I've made this simple route to test the variables:
Route::get('/', function () {
    dd([
        'APP_ENV' => env('APP_ENV'),
        'DB_CONNECTION' => env('DB_CONNECTION')
    ]);
});

I'm currently using the DB_CONNECTION=sqlite on my .env.testing, and DB_CONNECTION=mysql on my .env,
If I change my .env APP_ENV=testing, it shows the testing string:
array:2 [▼ // routes/web.php:7
  "APP_ENV" => "testing"
  "DB_CONNECTION" => "mysql"
]

But doesn't actually load my .env.testing vars, as you can see, it still loads mysql from my .env instead of .env.example.
The only way I figured out to make it work, is changing the app.php and chaining this at the end of ->create() method:
->create()->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');

Now it loads correctly:
array:2 [▼ // routes/web.php:7
  "APP_ENV" => "testing"
  "DB_CONNECTION" => "sqlite"
]

The problem is, I need it to be changed dynamically, or at least a way to change it inside my Docker container running my app, I want to be able to switch my variables to local and testing, so I've two environments to test it on my browser.
Of course, somehow running tests with PHPUnit work just fine, it loads the .env.testing correctly, but it seems to be possible because Laravel recreate the application every time you run tests with some custom boot logic for PHPUnit.

I found the problem solved in this post, you can refer to it.
Laravel 5 : Use different database for testing and local
